# Rotate imageview in place that isn't in the middle

Tags: android, rotation

I'm attempting to rotate an imageView in place while it is not in the middle. I'm using RotateAnimation, and here is my code:

```
int x = imageView.getLeft();
int y = imageView.getTop();
Animation rotate = new RotateAnimation((float) 0, (float) 359, (float) x, (float) y);
imageView.setAnimation(rotate);
```

When I do this, the imageView does not rotate in place, instead it rotates around a pivot point off of the screen. However, when I ran it in debugging mode, x and y equated to 300 and 352, which seems right. Can someone explain why the imageView is rotating around some other pivot point instead of the ones I set for it?

Comment: you want to rotate in the center right?

Comment: the center of the imageview, yes (not the center of the screen)

Comment: Check my code. it will work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

create the `rotate.xml`  file in anim folder  and use following code

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <rotate xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:duration="1600"
    android:fromDegrees="0"
    android:interpolator="@android:anim/linear_interpolator"
    android:pivotX="50%"
    android:pivotY="50%"
    android:repeatCount="infinite"
    android:toDegrees="358" />
```

and in Activity

```
myImage.startAnimation(AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(MainActivity.this,
                R.anim.rotate));
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
public static android.graphics.BitmapFactory.Options getSize(Context c, int resId){
        android.graphics.BitmapFactory.Options o = new android.graphics.BitmapFactory.Options();
        o.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
        BitmapFactory.decodeResource(c.getResources(), resId, o);
        return o;
    }
```

This returns an Options object that will contain the actual width and height. From an Activity you could use it like this:

```
ImageView img = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.yourImageViewId);
Options o = getSize(this, R.drawable.yourImage);
Matrix m = new Matrix();
m.postRotate(angle, o.outWidth/2, o.outHeight/2);
img.setScaleType(ScaleType.MATRIX);
img.setImageMatrix(m);
```